# Django manage.py custom command on Heroku

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, heroku, django-manage.py

I am trying to run a cron job with a Heroku hosted website.  I am using a Django back-end.  I have written a custom manage.py command that works locally (status_crawl.py).  I have seen a few guides and posts on how to fix this, but the suggestions did not work (such as [Running Django custom manage.py task on Heroku - Importing Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380733/running-django-custom-manage-py-task-on-heroku-importing-issues) and [this guide](http://tomatohater.com/2012/01/17/custom-django-management-commands-on-heroku/)).

Even weirder is that it is recognizing the other commands.  (And I managed to get the basic task to work by using runscript from the django-extensions framework).  It is still bothering me though.

My basic file structure likes like:

```
 likes:
   ...
   management:
      __init__.py
      commands:
      __init__.py
      status_crawl.py
```

The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named commands.status_crawl
```

The other weird thing is that when I run 'heroku run python manage.py help' the command is showing up as an option.  It's just not running when I try to run the script myself using the manage.py command.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's related to your PYTHONPATH variable on Heroku. This variable on Heroku may differ from your local PYTHONPATH. Try to import from the root of your project, like:

```
from likes.management.commands import status_crawl
```